# Values won't update after api call with axios

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, axios, use-effect

I'm trying to fetch data with axios using React's useEffect in two steps:

1- Get the access token with a POST request
2- Use the token on another POST request to get the desired data

After the first post request, the response returns as expected, but the state value doesn't update. So it sends undefined as the token for the second request.

```
const [infos, setInfos] = useState(null)
const [token, setToken] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    const getToken = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(
          'adress',
          {
            username: 'root',
            password: 'i_want_my_token',
          }
        )

        setToken(response.data.access)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }

    getToken()

    const getCatalogo = async () => {
      try {
        let data = { id: 6 }
        let configCatalogo = {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
        const catalogoResponse = await axios
          .post(
            'adress',
            data,
            configCatalogo
          )
       setInfos(res.data)
      } catch (error) {
           console.log(error) }
    }

    getCatalogo()
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function to get/set your `token` is asynchronous, you need to use two different `useEffect`s: one to fetch the token and one to use that token once it is set.

```
const [infos, setInfos] = useState(null)
const [token, setToken] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    const getToken = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(
          'adress',
          {
            username: 'root',
            password: 'i_want_my_token',
          }
        )

        setToken(response.data.access)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }

    getToken()
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCatalogo = async () => {
      try {
        let data = { id: 6 }
        let configCatalogo = {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
        const catalogoResponse = await axios
          .post(
            'adress',
            data,
            configCatalogo
          )
       setInfos(res.data)
      } catch (error) {
           console.log(error) }
    }

    getCatalogo()
  }, [token]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that I could use more than one useEffect.